# "Feature not supported" error when using the method first() of ResultSet

Tags: java, ucanaccess

I have an Access Database and I want to check if a query returns something. In order to do this, I have this method:

```
public boolean checkIfIdExists(int id){
    PreparedStatement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    boolean found = false;
    try {
        st = conn.prepareStatement("Select * from contacts where Id = " + id);
        rs = st.executeQuery();
        if (rs.first() == true) {
            found = true;
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return found;
}
```

But I receive this error:

```
SEVERE: null
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.4 característica no soportada
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessResultSet.first(UcanaccessResultSet.java:168)
    at mod.Conexion.checkIfIdExists(Conexion.java:82)
    at mod.ContactImporter.metodo(ContactImporter.java:70)
    at mod.Mod.main(Mod.java:18)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: característica no soportada
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.notSupported(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCResultSet.checkNotForwardOnly(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCResultSet.first(Unknown Source)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessResultSet.first(UcanaccessResultSet.java:166)
    ... 3 more
```

In English, the error means "feature not supported". I've tried looking into the error, but I didn't find anything. If this method doesn't work, how can I check if a ResultSet is empty?

Thank you

Comment: The API tells you that the error means that the JDBC driver does not support this method. The solution is not to use it and instead to choose another that *is* supported.

Comment: Your database engine does not support this `rs.first()`, have you tried using the *common* approach `while (rs.next()) { /* do stuff here */ }`?

Comment: Side note: `if (rs.first() == true)` could be simplified to `if ( rs.first() )`

Answer (score 4):

The problem is NOT that `first` is not supported by the database.

The problem is that it is not supported for this resultset.  The code for the HSQLDB `JDBCResultSet::first` looks like this:

```
public boolean first() throws SQLException {
    checkClosed();
    checkNotForwardOnly();
    if (isOnInsertRow || isRowUpdated) {
        throw Util.sqlExceptionSQL(ErrorCode.X_24513);
    }
    return navigator.first();
}
```

The exception is being thrown in the `checkNotForwardOnly` method.

And the implementation is

```
private void checkNotForwardOnly() throws SQLException {
    if (!isScrollable) {
        throw Util.notSupported();
    }
}
```

In other words, that `first()` (and `last()`) are only available for scrollable resultsets.

---

You can find a general explanation of JDBC scrollable resultsets [here](https://www.onlinetutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-scrollable-resultset-example-tutorials.html).

---

But as others have pointed out, you don't *need* to use `first()` in this example.  You can use a `next()` call to test if the `ResultSet` has any rows.